# Ionic Ajax Call when ion-checkbox is checked

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a database update if a checkbox is checked.   Is there a way to do it with Ionic?  I don't want to refresh the view or go to a different view.  Looking to do similar to the facebook like on the web.

ion-checkbox ng-model="myvalue"

Comment: yes you can do it use **$http.put** method when checkbox is checked in your controller

Comment: Thanks Mohan.  You should have answered it in the answer to get points.   This works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Basically you could to one of two thigs.

1) Create a ng-click on the checkbox that then calls a method on the controller which then calls a $http.put or whatever you like. you could pass the value to the method or just read it from the model.

2) By putting a watch on myValue like this:

```
 $scope.$watch('myValue', function() {
        alert('myValue has changed!');
    });
```